# Display appropriate message when JSON object is empty

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am successfully returning JSON from a PHP script, but I am having trouble displaying the appropriate message if the JSON object is empty.

The message is being displayed in an HTML UL tag with an ID of `#precommentsload`.

So here is the jQuery sending and returning the data from the PHP script:

```
 $.post("api/searchComments.php", {uid:uid}, function(data)
 {
   if(data == '[]') // here's where I'm checking if JSON object is empty
   {
     console.log('no data'); // console displays this message when empty
     // here's where I'm trying to output a message
     var obj = JSON.parse(data);
     $('#precommentsload').empty();
     var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function(item)
     {
       return '<li>There were no comments.</li>';
     }).join('');
     $('#precommentsload').html(htmlToInsert);
   }
   else
   {
     console.log(data); // when object returns data, I can see it here
     var obj = JSON.parse(data)
     $('#precommentsload').empty();
     var htmlToInsert = obj.map(function (item)
     {
       return '<li><b>' + item.add_date + ' - ' + item.add_user + '</b> 
       <br />' + item.comment.replace(/\r\n/g, '<br />') + '</li>';
       // no problem displaying comments when object is not empty
     }).join('');
     $('#precommentsload').html(htmlToInsert);      
   }
 });
```

After the $.post, I tried this IF statement:

```
 if(data == []) // without the single quotes
```

But I only returned [] to the console when object is empty.

The point is, when the object is not empty, I can display the message accordingly.

It's getting the 'There were no comments' to display when the object is empty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`var obj = JSON.parse(data);` is returning an empty array. When you try to do `.map` the callback function you provide is never executed because it only executes on items in the array.

Instead why don't you skip all of that and just do

```
var htmlToInsert = '<li>There were no comments.</li>'
$('#precommentsload').html(htmlToInsert);
```

Comment: YES!!!!  That was what I was looking for, and it worked.  Thank you, good sir.  Thank you very much.